# Homology Group of Infinite-dimensional Vector Space without a point

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X=C[0,1]$ be the normed vector space with maximum norm. Give it the norm-topology. Let $Y=X-\{0\}$. Find $H_n(Y)$.

Intuitively, I guess the answer is 0 for all $n$, but I have no idea.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198/how-do-you-show-that-s-infty-is-contractible

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Consider $H_t(x)={{tx}\over{\|x\|}}+(1-t)x$ It it a deformation retract between $S^{\infty}$ and $E-\{0\}$. $S^{\infty}$ is contractible.

Comment: I do not think that $Y$ is a CW complex. It has the homotopy type of one though so this argument is fixable and a very nice way to think of this.

Comment: Can you expand the argument that an embedded $S^n$ is contained in a finite-dimensional subspace?  I might believe that embedded spheres are limits of spheres embedded in finite-dimensional subspaces, but I don't see a reason for this to be true in the limit.

Comment: @KyleMiller: I actually think this is not true on the nose: However you can always homotope a map out of a $n$ dimensional submanifold it to be embedded in a $2n$ hyperplane. The proof should follow the lines of Whitney's embedding theorem.